# Cannot get incremented value inside for loop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, for-loop

I have a for loop which is supposed to loop twice. I want to use the incremented values (1 and 2) to set *id*. However, it gives me value 3 in both cases.

Here is my code:

```
for(var i=1; i<=2; i++) { //Add two options by default
  this.setState(prevState => ({ //add option Object with default attributes
    options_array: [...prevState.options_array, { id: i,
                                                  description: '',
                                                  value: null  }], 
  })) 
}
```

Comment: use `let` instead of `var`

Comment: Build the new state in the loop, then call `setState`, once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `let` instead of `var` in `for` loop.

Comment: thank you very much! It did solve the problem. Could you, please, enlighten me on the cause of it?

Comment: its because of scope of variable ,where let scope will delete for every loop but var scope remains.

Comment: @UmarAdkhamov https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the `setState` function in a unique closure for different `i`, otherwise they will share the same reference.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 2; i++) { //Add two options by default
    (i => this.setState(prevState => ({ //add option Object with default attributes
        options_array: [...prevState.options_array, {
            id: i,
            description: '',
            value: null
        }],
    })))(i);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. However, using let instead of var solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this:

```
let newArray = [];
for(var i=1; i<=2; i++) { //Add two options by default
newArray.push({ id: i,description: '',value: null  });
}

  this.setState(prevState => ({ //add option Object with default attributes
    options_array: [...prevState.options_array, ...newArray], 
  }))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var objectsArray = [];

for(var i=1; i<=2; i++) {
  objectsArray.push(
    {
      id: i,
      description: '',
      value: null
    }
  )
}

this.setState(prevState => ({
    options_array: [...prevState.options_array, ...objectsArray], 
}))
```

Try like this.